# Create new list from old list

Tags: python, list

I have a list with 5 elements, x+2, x^3+x^2+x+2, x^3+x^2+2, x^3+2x^2+2x+2, x^3+2x+2. I am trying to get a big list with elements like `(x+2)(x^3+x^2+x+2), (x+2)(x^3+x^2+x+2)(x^3+x^2+2)` and so on. One element multiply the other four to get a new element. The only way I know is to use For loop to do it, but it doesn't give me the right list. Here is what I have:

```
L = ['x+2','x^3+x^2+x+2','x^3+x^2+2','x^3+2x^2+2x+2','x^3+2x+2']

for i in range(0,len(L)): 
    for j in range(1,len(L)):
        for k in range(2,len(L)):
            for l in range(3,len(L)):
                for m in range(4,len(L)):
                    print L[i],L[j],L[k],L[l],L[m]
```

I have many repeat elements, I want to know to how to avoid to have those repeat elements while generate the list. Can someone tell me how to do it?

Comment: Do you want all combinations of your list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) function to get all combinations of a list:

```
from itertools import combinations
    result = []
    for i in range(1,len(L)):
        result.append(list(combinations(L,i))
    result # [[('x+2',), ('x^3+x^2+x+2',), ('x^3+x^2+2',), ('x^3+2x^2+2x+2',), ('x^3+2x+2',)], [('x+2', 'x^3+x^2+x+2'), ('x+2', 'x^3+x^2+2'), ('x+2', 'x^3+2x^2+2x+2'), ('x+2', 'x^3+2x+2'), ('x^3+x^2+x+2', 'x^3+x^2+2'), ('x^3+x^2+x+2', 'x^3+2x^2+2x+2'), ('x^3+x^2+x+2', 'x^3+2x+2'), ('x^3+x^2+2', 'x^3+2x^2+2x+2'), ('x^3+x^2+2', 'x^3+2x+2'), ('x^3+2x^2+2x+2', 'x^3+2x+2')], [('x+2', 'x^3+x^2+x+2', 'x^3+x^2+2'), ('x+2', 'x^3+x^2+x+2', 'x^3+2x^2+2x+2'), ('x+2', 'x^3+x^2+x+2', 'x^3+2x+2'), ('x+2', 'x^3+x^2+2', 'x^3+2x^2+2x+2'), ('x+2', 'x^3+x^2+2', 'x^3+2x+2'), ('x+2', 'x^3+2x^2+2x+2', 'x^3+2x+2'), ('x^3+x^2+x+2', 'x^3+x^2+2', 'x^3+2x^2+2x+2'), ('x^3+x^2+x+2', 'x^3+x^2+2', 'x^3+2x+2'), ('x^3+x^2+x+2', 'x^3+2x^2+2x+2', 'x^3+2x+2'), ('x^3+x^2+2', 'x^3+2x^2+2x+2', 'x^3+2x+2')], [('x+2', 'x^3+x^2+x+2', 'x^3+x^2+2', 'x^3+2x^2+2x+2'), ('x+2', 'x^3+x^2+x+2', 'x^3+x^2+2', 'x^3+2x+2'), ('x+2', 'x^3+x^2+x+2', 'x^3+2x^2+2x+2', 'x^3+2x+2'), ('x+2', 'x^3+x^2+2', 'x^3+2x^2+2x+2', 'x^3+2x+2'), ('x^3+x^2+x+2', 'x^3+x^2+2', 'x^3+2x^2+2x+2', 'x^3+2x+2')]]
```

Comment: How do I get  rid of the extra comma next to an element?

Comment: @Simple , It's not an important issue , because it's an tuple with just one element , you can use `t[0]` for get ride of with `t = (something,)`

Answer (score 1):

The word you're looking for is permutations

Python has [that ability included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python) in the itertools package